# Как применить два тега к переменной в PHP?

Tags: php, foreach

Нужно вывести данные массива (дни недели). Выходные - выделить жирным шрифтом, причем текущий день - выделить курсивом. 
Код получился такой:

```
<?php
            $arr = ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'];
            $day = 'Sun';

            foreach ($arr as $elem) {
                if ($elem === 'Sat' || $elem === 'Sun') {
                    echo '<b>'.$elem.'</b>'.' ';
                } 
                elseif ($elem === $day) {
                    echo '<em>'.$elem.'</em>';
                }
                else {
                    echo $elem.' ';
                }
            }        

        ?>
```

Проблема в том, что если указать в переменной выходной, который выделяется жирным, выделить курсивом его уже не получается. А вот будние дни выделяются. 
Спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Исправил. На здоровье.
Сделал быстренько 2 решения:

```
            $arr = ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'];
            $day = 'Sun';

echo 'Пример через FOR<br><br>';
            for ($i=0;$i<sizeof($arr);$i++)
            {
                if($arr[$i]=='Sat' || $arr[$i]=='Sun')
                {
                    if ($arr[$i]==$day)
                    echo '<b><em>'.$arr[$i].'</em></b>'.' ';
                    else
                    echo '<b>'.$arr[$i].'</b>'.' ';

                }else if($arr[$i]==$day){
                echo '<b><em>'.$arr[$i].'</em></b>'.' ';
                }else{
                    echo $arr[$i].'&nbsp;';
                }
            }

echo '<br><br>Пример через FOREACH<br><br>';

            foreach ($arr as $elem) {
                if ($elem == 'Sat' || $elem == 'Sun') {
                    if ($elem == $day)
                    echo '<b><em>'.$elem.'</em></b>'.' ';
                    else                
                    echo '<b>'.$elem.'</b>'.' ';
                }else if($elem==$day){
                echo '<b><em>'.$elem.'</em></b>'.' ';
                }
                else {
                    echo $elem.' ';
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'];
$day = 'Sun';

foreach ($arr as $elem) {
     $html = $elem;
    if ($elem === $day) {
        $html = '<em>'.$html.'</em>';
    }

    if ($elem === 'Sat' || $elem === 'Sun') {
        $html =  '<b>'.$html.'</b>';
    }

    echo $html.' ';

}
```

Извините, пишу с телефона))